# "Where are you from?" answer

Tags: word-choice

Where are you from? - A guy asked me while we were in Bangkok.

- I have been in Bankok my whole life.
- I have been in Bangkok since my birth.
- I have lived in Bangkok my whole life.

Which answer is the most preferable for native speakers ?

Comment: Maybe, *I was born and brought up in Bangkok.*

Comment: Your third option is best.  Your first option is okay, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some typical responses:

- "I'm from here." + [any of the sentences you provided].
- "I'm from here.  I've lived here my whole life."
- "I'm from here.  I was born here in Bankok, and I've lived here my whole life."
- "I was born here, and have lived here my whole/entire life."

My first example includes the reference to your sentences, since I encourage you to feel confident with speaking the way you feel natural or what you want to express. Especially *since you're asking what is natural* you're likely to develop a natural style of your own.

Note: In this case, *whole life* and *entire life* mean the same thing.

Comment: The guy asked me while we are in Bangokok.

Comment: I like this variant, "I'm from here. Born and raised."